# import error on python when running on localhost

Tags: python, localhost, importerror, cgi-bin

I have already installed "textblob" package for python, and it works on the machine.

```
constantinopolis@constantinopolis:~$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>>
```

But when I try to run a python application on localhost which imports "textblob", it gives import error.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the same python on the local host and when you tested the "TextBlob" package? Alternative is the PYTHONPATH different for the two ways of starting python - which may cause your installed module to be overlooked?

You probably need to give us some more information to help answer this.

Comment: OK - they are using the same version of python but are they invoking pythin from the same place? It looks like when invokling it from localhost you are calling /usr/bin/python. Do 'which python' in your command shell to see if this is the same python being called. After that you will need to check the Pythonpath is the same - have python do import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)

Comment: Could you explain more detailed?

Comment: I think you should use the shell command 'find python' in order to check ou are suing the same python installation (/usr/bin/python) when you invovke something on your local host. If they are not different then I think thre must be a difference in the PYTHONPATH environment variable in the two ways you are calling python. You can check that from withing python by using os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)  - put this in a script and look at the output both from the command line and your browser to see if the enviroment variable is the same.

Comment: I'm using /usr/bin/python.